# (Java Beginner) - Having trouble with a program

Tags: java

Ok so I am working on a program that involves loans and gives information to the user about loans from what the user inputs.

The purpose of this program I am writing is for the user to be asked to input a loan amount and the number of years that they have to pay it off. Once the user has given this information, the program will take the loan amount and number of years and tell the user the annual interest rate, monthly payment and the total amount. 
ALSO, if the user enters a loan amount of -1, the program is supposed to terminate.

Below is my code thus far:

```
package Loans;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loans {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        double monthlyInterestRate;
        double annualInterestRate;
        double monthlyPayment;
        double total;
        double numberOfYears;
        double loanAmount;

        System.out.println("This program will compute the monthly payments and total payments for a loan amount on interest rates starting at 5%, incrementing by 1/8th percent up to 8%.");

        //Formula to Calculate Monthly Interest Rate:
        monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate/1200);

        //Formula to Calculate Monthly Payment:
        monthlyPayment = (loanAmount*monthlyInterestRate);

        //Formula To Calculate Annual Interest Rate:
        annualInterestRate = (1-(Math.pow(1/(1 + monthlyInterestRate), numberOfYears * 12)));

        //Formula To Calculate The Total Payment:
        total = (monthlyPayment*numberOfYears*12);

        while(true)
        {


            System.out.println("Please enter in the loan amount.");
            double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter in the number of years.");
            double numberOfYears = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Interest Rate: " + annualInterestRate);
            System.out.println("Monthly Payment: " + monthlyPayment);
            System.out.println("Total Payment: " + total);

            }
    }
}
```

This does not compile and I'm not sure why. (Again, I'm a beginner)

The errors I am receiving are on the line that reads "double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();" AND the line that reads "double numberOfYears = input.nextDouble();".

The error for the first line says, "Duplicate local variable loanAmount".

The error for the second line says, "Multiple markers at this line
    - Line breakpoint:Loans [line: 39] - 
     main(String[])
    - Duplicate local variable numberOfYears"

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't link us to weird places.

Comment: Your code could have been included here in the question easily enough

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811)

Comment: I used pastie for ease to the reader because I thought including everything in the question may seem cumbersome and readers would not feel like looking at it.

Comment: The code that you posted does not compile. So you didn't even attempt to understand the compilation errors.

Comment: I will re-post it and be more specific as well as include everything in the question.

Comment: @Ian2thedv I know it doesn't compile. That's why I am here. Because I don't understand WHY what I'm doing isn't working. That seems kind of clear

Comment: @Alan: always include the exact (copy/paste) error message you're getting from the compiler when you have this sort of problem. Saves a lot of time. This is true for every error you'll get - always include the exact message, not a "description" of the error/problem. People are used to reading them and can help you more quickly that way.

Comment: @AlanStrong are you using an IDE? Compilations issues are usually quite clear and it is easy to deduce from the error message what is wrong. Maybe try to understand the error, then post your understanding of the error message.

Comment: @Ian2thedv I did try to figure out what the errors mean, but I'm not sure. I edited the question and included the errors I get. 'duplicate local variable' -doesn't really make sense to me because even when I remove the initial line that initializes the variables, it gives me different errors. I tried Googling the errors but I can't find any solutions that help me understand what I need to change about MY code to fix the problem. 

Thanks for the feedback. I suppose I will just power through this one alone. I have a week til it's due anyway.

Comment: 1. You're re-declaring the same variable - remove the `double` in front of your loop variables. 2. Your formulas are run in order, *before* your program has read the user's input - you need to move them below the user input and put them in the correct order. 3. Your `annualInterestRate` and `monthlyInterestRate` are defined based on each other. Do you not have a starting value for one (or both) so you can calculate the other?

Comment: @AlanStrong you are declaring the variables twice. When initialising variables separately for declaration you don't need the type. And you said you get different errors, these are just more compilations issues that you have to solve. You are *almost* half way there

Comment: @thegrinner OK thank you so much... I initialized the variable 'annualInterestRate' and that made it compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is pretty much self explanatory. You have defined both "loanAmount" and "numberOfYears" two times in main. Either rename them or declare them only once.

If you are a beginner in coding I would recommend you use an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans. They will point out compilation errors along with suggestions on how to fix them.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I actually have been wanting to use Eclipse because of that exact reason... But in my class, my professor forces us to use Dr. Java (just because it's what SHE likes). Perhaps I will just use it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Dr Java :) never heard of it!!

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough to fix. So the issue is that in this segment:

```
        System.out.println("Please enter in the loan amount.");
        double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter in the number of years.");
        double numberOfYears = input.nextDouble();
```

You are re-defining your double variables loanAmount and numberOfYears, which is going to cause an error. Take out the "double" in both lines where they are used.

The other change you need to make is to intialize these variables at the top of your code. Change the lines where you initialize all of your double variables and set them equal to 0, for example:

```
    double annualInterestRate = 0;
    double numberOfYears = 0;
    double loanAmount = 0;
```

When a variable has a call in a program, it must first be initialized. It doesn't matter what it's initialized to, since its end value will be determined by the program's actions, but it absolutely needs to be initialized at some point.

I made exactly these changes and the program compiled successfully.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! :) That makes sense and I understand this program completely now after some talking with my professor. This also helped make extra sense of it. 

Thanks for the response!